# Is there a way to save only certain url using lynx, or at least skip externals usrls?

Tags: save, lynx

As title, I'm trying to save the links of a website, but I'd like to save only the links that points to a certain urls (and skip some pages and external urls). Is there a way to do it with lynx? Thanks

I used the "lynx -dump -listonly URL > file.txt" but I can't find nothing about skipping some urls.